# merge two arrays without duplicates in java

Tags: java, arrays

I wonder if there is any way to merge two different arrays to one array without duplicates values.
This must work in time efficiency of O(n+m).

```
n= a.length (first array)
m = b.length (second array)
```

Nodes:

- each array including the result array is not necessary in order.
- assurance there is no duplicates value in each of the array itself.

There is no limit for the place efficiency but it is not valid to use  the solution of creating a new array in length of the maximum value in both array and then place each value in the right index according to the value. The reason being that if the maximum value is 1 billion it means that i need to create an array with billion cells.

Comment: Java arrays are static in size. The only way to merge arrays is to create a new one. Your requirements are impossible.

Comment: You can do it in 2 steps: Merge into collection -> convert to array (e.g. List.toArray() method)

Comment: sorry if i didn't explain myself , i meant that is not possible to create array that depend on one of the value of the array. for example if my array is {4,5,6,5} and { 6,5,3,2,20} so one solution for this is to create new array with  size 20 and then pass cell by cell and insert each value to his relevant index for example value 4 will go to cell 4 (in the new array ) and value 3 will go to  cell 3.. and so on , the problem in this way is that is required at list 20 cells in my array .. and if i received a very high number i getting  out of memory( logic ).

Comment: so , i don't really care if you create a new array the only thing is that it should not be depend on one of the values .. of course we must first create new array with at list m+n size ...i don't have any problem with that , and about the idea with the collection it should work but im looking for solution without collection or others abstract object ...(except array)..

Answer (score 0):

We need to declare size at the time of array declaration. so after that we can't modify.
With out new array we can't merge.

In my view it's better to use collection

Answer (score 0):

not the most pretty but it works.

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    int [] one = {1,2,3,6,7,9,10};
    int [] two = {1,2,4,5,7,8,10};

    List three = new ArrayList();
    for(int x = 0; x < one.length; x++){
        three.add(one[x]);
    }
    for(int z  = 0; z < two.length; z++){
        if(!three.contains(two[z])){
            three.add(two[z]);
        }
    }
    java.util.Collections.sort(three);
    System.out.println(three.toString());
}
```

**EDIT** ok well i failed to read the part about efficiency but w/e